# VB.net Labels not refreshing (Me.Refresh() )

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using VB.net to create an application, I have never used VB.net before, so I probably have no idea what I'm doing.

My problem is my form will not refresh labels, I have tried using Me.Refresh(), Me.Update(), I've tried invalidating the controls before refreshing, I've even tried Application.DoEvents() (though I know this isn't recommended).

Here are two snippets, one showing the point in the code where a variable is changed, the other showing the label the variable is displayed on.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(CType(sender, Control), e.Location)
    End If
    Functionality.selectedTask = 0
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

When this (Label1) is clicked, Label11 should update (Label1 represents task 0).

```
Me.Label11.Text = Convert.ToString(Functionality.selectedTask)
```

This is how I'm testing to see whether Label11 updates or not (in the final program this should show a description of the selected task). It starts out with the selected task at 15, but will not change. I'm certain variables themselves are changing, but this change is just not represented.

Comment: `Me.Label11.Text = Convert.ToString(Functionality.selectedTask)` is not in the click event - how is it supposed to do this. Where is this code?

Comment: reply to OneFineDay: It's in a seperate part of the program --it is in the Form1.Designer.vb, where the variables are initialised.

Comment: Then it will never change.

Comment: Well there's your problem. The designer file is only called when the form is being instantiated. Put your code in the Form.Load() event or better yet, put it in the method that handles the event which should change the control. Never ever edit the Designer file. There are very few use cases where editing the designer file will achieve what you are looking to do, and those are edge cases.

Comment: You should not be changing code in that file anyway.

Comment: Put the 2nd snippet in the 1st snippet, replacing Me.Refresh().

Comment: Thanks guys, it's a stupid mistake I know. Being unfamiliar with VB I expected the designer file to be a real time update. Thanks!

Comment: Never touch the code in the designer...

Comment: FYI the ContextMenu is typically opened from a control's ContextMenuStrip property, not via a the .Show method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short example of how to change a `Label`'s text with a `Button.Click` event. You should be able to just copy paste this into a new VB.NET Windows Forms Application:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents newLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Private WithEvents newButton As New System.Windows.Forms.Button

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        newLabel.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        newLabel.Text = "Orignial value"

        newButton.Location = New Point(10, 40)
        newButton.AutoSize = True
        newButton.Text = "Change the label"

        Me.Controls.Add(newLabel)
        Me.Controls.Add(newButton)

    End Sub


    Public Sub changeTheLabel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles newButton.Click
        Me.newLabel.Text = "Text Changed"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ignore most of the code: Label.Text = "Text Changed" will update the label.

Comment: @rheitzman, you are correct the `Me.newLabel.Text = "Text Changed"` code bit will in fact change the label's text so long as the calling thread owns the label control. However, the question specifically said that the label should be updated when another control was clicked and the code above is a short , complete, and verifiable solution that shows the requested behavior.